# Java 10 and liquibase-maven-plugin update not finding java/sql/Driver

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

I'm currently upgrading my Integration Tests from Java 8 to Java 10. However, when I run any of my integration tests when JAVA_HOME is set to Java 10, I get the following error when running the liquibase-maven-plugin update is called:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update (update-schema) on project econiq-rest-it: Execution update-schema of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update failed: A required class was missing while executing org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update: java/sql/Driver
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/sryan/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin/3.6.2/liquibase-maven-plugin-3.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/sryan/.m2/repository/com/econiq/db/econiq-db-h2/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/econiq-db-h2-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/sryan/.m2/repository/com/econiq/db/econiq-db-common/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/econiq-db-common-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/sryan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.4/plexus-utils-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/sryan/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.6.2/liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/sryan/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.18/snakeyaml-1.18.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/sryan/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/sryan/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>com.econiq.rest:econiq-rest-it:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : java.sql.Driver
```

I know liquibase does run with Java 10 as I also have a separate pom.xml that starts a standalone WildFly 14 server and where I run in any updated schema using the liquibase-maven-plugin and that works fine. Totally confused as to why when I run it as an integration test it can't find a java.sql.Driver.

I'm using the latest liquibase-maven-plugin 3.6.2 but I do see that it's using an older version of plexus-utils and so I'm wondering if the older plexus-utils is causing the issue. Anybody else had a similar when using liquibase in Java 10?

Comment: In Java 10 the liquibase-maven-plugin might need an update cause it can't access java.sql.Driver which is an different java module...

Comment: Unfortunately 3.6.2 is the latest liquibase-maven-plugin. I have a workaround for now by using the exec-maven-plugin to call liquibase externally to create the db required for the integration tests. This works until I figure out which dependent jar is causing the issue as I don't believe it's liquibase that is causing the problem.